# Повелительное наклонение от "от(за)купорить"

Tags: грамотная-речь, окончания

Викисловарь даёт повелительное наклонение от *[откупорить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)* одно — *отк**у**порь*, а от [*закупорить*](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) — два: *зак**у**порь* и *зак**у**пори.* Откуда берётся эта разница, и какой для второго глагола вариант предпочтителен? Первый (с мягким знаком)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Викисловарь - не аргумент в подобных вопросах. Скорее всего, составители просто забыли про один из вариантов, некогда считавшийся основным. Читайте лучше Пушкина.

(...) Бомарше
Говаривал мне: "Слушай, брат Сальери,
Как мысли черные к тебе придут,
Откупори шампанского бутылку
Иль перечти "Женитьбу Фигаро".

*Обратите внимание: здесь по тексту и так идут постоянные перебои ритма, так что отговорка, что это для лишнего слога сделано, не работает.*

//---

О предпочтительности не берусь судить. Мне в обоих случаях ближе полные варианты - откупори и закупори.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я тоже тогда буду склоняться к тому, чтобы на полный ориентироваться, действительно, так лучше, по крайней мере когда ударение делаешь, как положено, на У.

Answer (score -1):

Откуда берется разница в образовании повелительной формы глагола? Для ответа на этот вопрос желательно обратиться к грамматическим справочникам.

**1) Существуют стандартные способы образования**

**Суффикс И** образует повелительное наклонение, если ударение в ОНВ (основе настоящего времени) падает на окончание во всех лицах или только в форме 1-го лица: *несёт, несу – неси, пишет, пишу – пиши, таит, таю – таи, учит, учу – учи.*

**Суффикс И** употребляется без учета ударения в двух случаях:
1. Когда основа оканчивается на группу согласных (стукнут – стукни, умолкнут – умолкни);
2. Когда глагол имеет приставку вы-, которая перетягивает на себя ударение (вынесут – вынеси, выберут – выбери).

**Нулевой суффикс употребляется в тех случаях, если ударение в настоящем времени падает на основу** (режут – режь, верят – верь, играют – играй).

**2) Существуют нестандартные способы образования** (пей, шей, ешь, дай, поезжай), **а также варианты:** высуни – высунь, прочисть – прочисти, уведомь – уведоми, полакомься – полакомись, закупорь – закупори, откупорь – откупори, порть – порти, корчь – корчи. (На слух глаголы с суффиксом И кажутся разговорными.)

**Итак, глаголы "откупорить и закупорить" относятся к вариантным.** Основной формой является нулевой суффикс, так как ударение в настоящем времени падает на основу (закУпорит - закУпорь, откУпорит - откУпорь), но суффикс И также применяется.

В Нацкорпусе можно посмотреть частотность употребления форм. "Закупорь и откупорь" используются, но редко; "закупори" не используется вовсе. Чаще всего применяется форма "откупори".

**Примеры**

― Не угодно ли отведать сыру… **Откупорь!** Это не кислые щи? [А. Ф. Вельтман. Приключения, почёрпнутые из моря житейского. Саломея (1848)]

― Теперь **закупорь,** заверни бутылку в газету и не забудь взять домой. [Юрий Дружников. Виза в позавчера (1968-1997)]

― Экой ты до лапок интересующийся. Да рябиновой новый штоф **откупори.** Садись супротив, хватим по лампадке. [Саша Черный. Солдатские сказки / Кабы я был царем (1932)]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!